# reload or run function from App-delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my App, the whole UI is based on a tintColor and i give the user an opportunity to choose a color by himself and i save that in `NSUserDefaults`

Here is code from my AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ThemeColor"])
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSData *colorData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: [UIColor orangeColor]];
        [defaults setObject: colorData forKey:@"ThemeColor"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        self.window.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    }
    else
    {
        NSData *colorData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ThemeColor"];
        UIColor *color = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:colorData];
        self.window.tintColor = color;
    }  
    return YES;
}
```

i give the user to change color in a UITableView, so how do i from didSelectRowAtIndex reload the above code (or something like that) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//AppDelegate.h
-(void)setUserColor;
//AppDelegate.m
-(void)setUserColor{
    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ThemeColor"])
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSData *colorData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: [UIColor orangeColor]];
        [defaults setObject: colorData forKey:@"ThemeColor"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        self.window.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    }
    else
    {
        NSData *colorData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ThemeColor"];
        UIColor *color = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:colorData];
        self.window.tintColor = color;
    }  

}
```

Then import AppDelegate.h and in did select

```
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   [delegate setUserColor];
```